# Oracle Rounding down

Tags: oracle, math, rounding

Here my partial statement. The statement works and receive the value of 4 but instead I would prefer 3.9 in some cases the number may not be a whole number but .4,.2,.1 etc.  Those numbers currently show up as "0" because Oracle rounds up.  If I remove "round" I receive 3.9123458543845474586.  Is there a way to display 3.9 only and .4,.2 etc. without the rounding?  I know its got to be a syntax issue. When I remove round I receive an error.

round((total_qty)*((avg_qty/(sum(avg_qty)over(partition by ID)))/5),0) avg_qty

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're getting an error when you remove `ROUND` that means you didn't remove it properly; be careful of your parentheses. Egor's answer will round to one decimal place, which is what I think you asked for. If you want one decimal place without rounding, use `TRUNC(x, 1)` instead. `TRUNC(4.56, 1)` returns `4.5`; `ROUND(4.56, 1)` returns `4.6`. One of these will be your answer.

Comment: I tried the above and I receive "missing parenthesis" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT ROUND(3.9123458543845474586, 1) Round FROM DUAL;

     Round
----------
      3.9
```

For better understanding please refer this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm).

Answer (score 12):

If you always want to "round" *down*, the function is `trunc`. This should work for you:

```
select trunc(3.99999, 1) from dual;
```

Result

```
3.9
```

Comment: It annoys me when people say "round up" or "round down", I always have to ask, "so you don't want Round, you want Ceiling or Floor?". They usually answer, "no, I want it Rounded to the nearest n. Round it up!" <sigh>