# Adjusting the result of query which is using round function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Suppose I have a query as:

Select round(column 1 - column 2) delta from table;

Now I want delta as delta -1 if (column 1 - column 2) results in a number with decimal value equal or more than 0.5 (like 100.65). Because the delta will be rounded to next whole number (like 101). But I want just delta (means 100 and not 101).

If (column 1 - column 2) results in a number with decimal value less than 0.5 (like 100.35) then the delta is automatically right (like 100 after rounding).

So the problem is occurring for rounding of (column 1 - column 2) when (column 1 - column 2) has a value greater than 0.5.

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking. `round(column 1 - column 2)` gives 100 for 100.35 and 101 for 100.65. If you want 100 in any case you don't round but trancate: `trunc(column 1 - column 2)`. Is this already what you are after?

Comment: Beside Thorsten's obviously correct answer, why are you asking the question about a difference of two columns? How is this different from just rounding or truncating any kind of value, regardless of how it is derived (a difference of columns, a single column, the product of quantity and price, etc.)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Rounding down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230601/oracle-rounding-down)